# Differences between Derivable rules and Admissible rules?

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages

Can anyone help me to explain and give examples for this question?

"There are two ways to introduce new reference rules: as derivable rules and as admissible rules.
What are the differences between them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Admissibility and derivability wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference) says:-

> A derivable rule is one whose conclusion can be derived from its
>   premises using the other rules. An admissible rule is one whose
>   conclusion holds whenever the premises hold. All derivable rules are
>   admissible. To appreciate the difference, consider the following set
>   of rules for defining the natural numbers

You may check out the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_rule) which says:-

> Every derivable rule is admissible, but not vice versa in general. A
>   logic is structurally complete if every admissible rule is derivable,
>   i.e., {\vdash }={\,|!!!\sim }.[5] In logics with a well-behaved
>   conjunction connective (such as superintuitionistic or modal logics),
>   a rule A_{1},\dots ,A_{n}/B is equivalent to A_{1}\land \dots \land
>   A_{n}/B with respect to admissibility and derivability. It is
>   therefore customary to only deal with unary rules A/B.